# How to Translate this double indexed for loop into an efficient one?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply, mapply

I'm new to R and here. I usethis site a lot but this time I'm stuck in a problem for which I cannot find a solution.

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A","A","B","B","B","C","D","D","D","D"),
             elapsed = c(10,15,5,7,20,4,3,4,15,16),
             val = c(5,8,1,2,4,6,7,9,8,3),
             acum = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

And I need to accumulate for each row, the total "val" from other rows with the same "id" and an "elapsed" not more than 5 units less the current (it's measured in seconds).

I.e.: I select one row, say i, and register its "val" **in** acum[i]. Then I look back the previous row, i-1. I check that it has the same ID than i an that its "elapsed" is not less than 5 that of the row i. If it is, I sum its value to the acum[i]. **I repeat the step with all superior lags**, and so on.

In order to do that, I called this loop:

```
 for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
   for(l in 0:nrow(df)) {
    if(l<i) {
      if (df[i,"id"]==df[i-l,"id"]) 
        {if (df[i,"elapsed"]-df[i-l,"elapsed"]<=5)
       {df$acum[i] <- df$acum[i]+df[i-l,"val"]}
      }
    } 
   }
 }

#    id elapsed val acum
# 1   A      10   5    0
# 2   A      15   8   13
# 3   B       5   1    1
# 4   B       7   2    3
# 5   B      20   4    4
# 6   C       4   6    6
# 7   D       3   7    7
# 8   D       4   9   16
# 9   D      15   8    8
# 10  D      16   3   11
```

The problem is that as the data.frame gets bigger, the loop spends more and more time doing this task (even several hours).

I surfed google and navigated Stackoverflow an everybody gives the same advise: Use the apply functions. But I cannot figure out how to do it in this case. Maybe mapply, but since I'm new in this I am not sure how.

Could anybody help me with this?

Thank you in advance, Santiago.-

Comment: With `dplyr`, maybe `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(acum = val + (lag(val, default = 0) * ifelse(lag(elapsed, default = 0) >= (elapsed - 5), 1, 0)))`

Comment: Almost! this is a great approach. But here it would consider only the first lag, and there can be rows in superior lags that meet the criteria and therefire should be summed.

Comment: @alistaire - please post your comment as a viable answer.

Comment: But @sfucci, you mention only one lag going back one row. You do not mention these other lags.

Comment: should that first value be a 0 or 5?

Comment: @rawr, good point, it's a mistake. The first value should be 5. However, improvement that function to get the 5 (I think it's a matter of indexes) will not improve the main issue with that, which is performance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating lagged variables by `id` group and then run an `ifelse()`.

```
# LAGGED GROUP VARIABLES
df$lastelapsed <- sapply(1:nrow(df),
                         function(i) sum((df$id[i-1] == df$id[i]) * df$elapsed[i-1]))
df$lastvalue <- sapply(1:nrow(df),
                         function(i) sum((df$id[i-1] == df$id[i]) * df$val[i-1]))

# ROW CALCULATION
df$acumtest <- ifelse((df$elapsed - df$lastelapsed) <= 5, df$val + df$lastvalue, df$val)
```

Comment: I think this is the winner. I tried to insert this in a for loop in order to consider superior order lags, but It seems computational infeasible (With 15K rows it was running more than an hour).

Then I will use a "second best" approach and I will use your solution adding the "last acumtest" instead of "lastvalue". So, if the "elapsed" for the first lag is not greather than 5, I will sume dhe acumtest of that lag to the present value.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! Glad you found a workaround. However, do consider @rawr's df solution with interesting benchmarks between approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new grouping variable based on the `elapsed > 5` criteria within each id, and then use your favorite aggregation tool

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A","A","B","B","B","C","D","D","D","D"),
                 elapsed = c(10,15,5,7,20,4,3,4,15,16),
                 val = c(5,8,1,2,4,6,7,9,8,3),
                 acum = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

within(df, {
  grp <- paste(id, ave(elapsed, id, FUN = function(x)
    cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x) > 5))))
  acum <- ave(val, grp, FUN = cumsum)
})

#    id elapsed val acum grp
# 1   A      10   5    5 A.0
# 2   A      15   8   13 A.0
# 3   B       5   1    1 B.0
# 4   B       7   2    3 B.0
# 5   B      20   4    4 B.1
# 6   C       4   6    6 C.0
# 7   D       3   7    7 D.0
# 8   D       4   9   16 D.0
# 9   D      15   8    8 D.1
# 10  D      16   3   11 D.1
```

Some benchmarks with the current solutions:

```
library('dplyr')
library('data.table')

rawr <- function(df) {
  df <- within(df, {
    grp <- paste(id, ave(elapsed, id, FUN = function(x)
      cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x) > 5))))
    acum <- ave(val, grp, FUN = cumsum)
    })
  df
}

## shitty data table version, I'm sure it's wrong
## rest assured someone will point it out
rawr_dt <- function(df) {
  dt <- as.data.table(df)
  dt[, grp := cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(elapsed) > 5)), by = 'id'][, acum := cumsum(val), c('id', 'grp')]
  dt[, grp := NULL]
  dt
}

sfucci <- function(df) {
  for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    for(l in 0:nrow(df)) {
      if(l<i) {
        if (df[i,"id"]==df[i-l,"id"]) 
        {if (df[i,"elapsed"]-df[i-l,"elapsed"]<=5)
        {df$acum[i] <- df$acum[i]+df[i-l,"val"]}
        }
      } 
    }
  }
  df
}

Parfait <- function(df) {
  df$lastelapsed <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) sum((df$id[i-1] == df$id[i]) * df$elapsed[i-1]))
  df$lastvalue <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) sum((df$id[i-1] == df$id[i]) * df$val[i-1]))
  df$acumtest <- ifelse((df$elapsed - df$lastelapsed) <= 5, df$val + df$lastvalue, df$val)
  df
}
alistaire <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(acum = val + (lag(val, default = 0) *
                           ifelse(lag(elapsed, default = 0) >= (elapsed - 5), 1, 0)))
}

acc <- rawr(df)$acum
identical(acc, rawr_dt(df)$acum)
# [1] TRUE
# identical(acc, sfucci(df)$acum)
identical(acc, Parfait(df)$acumtest)
# [1] TRUE
identical(acc, alistaire(df)$acum)
# [1] TRUE

library('microbenchmark')
microbenchmark(sfucci(df), rawr(df), rawr_dt(df), Parfait(df), alistaire(df), unit = 'relative')

# Unit: relative
#           expr       min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval   cld
#     sfucci(df) 11.596961 9.990698 10.082249 9.952529 10.220162 5.603044   100     e
#       rawr(df)  1.000000 1.000000  1.000000 1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100 a    
#    rawr_dt(df)  3.771649 3.483610  3.472160 3.436365  3.531379 1.945339   100    d 
#    Parfait(df)  3.392426 2.980234  3.008432 2.902410  3.006896 2.361832   100   c  
#  alistaire(df)  2.140693 2.042809  2.080444 2.028151  2.029965 2.638486   100  b
```

Comment: @Khashaa or you could simply point out that you one could use `>=` vs `>`. or use any other lag time. I hope you wrote down this "failing" case in your diary. what a victory for you